# "CurrentCellChanged" Event is not working when "PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Event is used at the same grid

Tags: c#, wpf

`CurrentCellChanged` Event is not working when `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` Event is used at the same DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid CurrentCellChanged="dgrRslt4Mdf_CellChanged"
          PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown**="ctrl_PreviewMouseButtonDown">
<DataGrid/>
```

Actually, I check `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` occurred first through Debug
If so, I use two events at the same DataGrid, isn't another(CurrentCellChanged) working?

Comment: What is `CellChanged` event. `Datagrid` by default does not raise this event. Check this link for all the events https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.7.2#events

Comment: I'm sorry to make you confused. Maybe that's CurrentCellChanged event, I guess